# can't install the rebuild app after signed using jarsign

Tags: android, apk, jarsigner, apktool

After I got a signed result I tried to install the `.apk` file, what failed ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI7Cy.png))

I deployed the `.apk` file

```
apktool d x.apk
```

then made some chagnes and rebuild the `.apk` using

```
apktool b x.app
```

I've download `root.crt` and `class3.crt` and updated the ca-certificate
created the ca-certificate on my name and use the ca-certificate to signed the `.apk`

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my_release_key.keystore /root/home/Desktop/x/dist/x.apk  john_release_key
```

I have installed jdk and jre version 1.8.0_121

But the `.apk` file wasn't installed.
how to go through the problem?